# How to read a nested value in a JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
  "version": 1.0,
  "object": {
    "a1": "a2",
    "b1": "b2
  },
  "deploy": {
    "applicationName": "app",
    "namespace": "com.abc.xyz"
    ...
  }
}
```

The `...` means the JSON continues more. I want to retrieve the `namespace` from this JSON. My code looks like this:

```
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
var result = rootNode.at("/deploy/namespace");
```

However, with this code, `result` will always `""`

I've tried different paths but I'm always getting an empty `String`.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `at` return a JsonNode, so you need to access it:

```
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
var result = rootNode.at("/deploy/namespace").asText();
```

Otherwise, you can also access it in this way:

```
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
var result = rootNode.path("deploy").path("namespace").asText();
```

Comment: Yeah I was missing the asText method. Thanks a lot